# Show 404 when {id} in route/{id} doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-5.8

For a website I'm building I need a blog/announcement page that can show the individual announcements on a separate page. While I have the display part working, I need to find a way to show a 404 when the {id} in the route isn't available or existing.

At the moment is shows the view without any data coming from the controller. Image below is an example of this.
[image: Clipboard]

Routes:
[image: Routes]

I hope this is enough information, if more is needed I'd love to hear.

Comment: You need to put the code in the question as text, not as pictures hosted somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to 'fail' when the id doesn't match anything is to use `findOrFail`

example controller code:

```
public function announcement($id) {
    $announcement = Announcement::findOrFail($id);

    return('example.view', compact('announcement'));
}
```

also as the person above said above alias names can't be the same

Answer (score 1):

Use findOrFail on to fetch the announcement on the controller, it will automaticlly redirect to 404 page if it didn`t find an instanse with the given id.

```
$announcement = Announcement::findOrFail($id);
```